# QT QML Translation retranslate

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm running *QT* `5.10.1` on Windows, the `app` is only made in `QML`. I'm trying to use the new `retranslate()` to change language during runtime. The current code is working fine with texts that use the `getEmptyString()` appended to it. But the rest of the text within `qsTr()` does not. `TranslationHandler.cpp` is empty and I haven't cleaned up the includes.

So I'm able to set a language from the QML using the context property. Also I checked so the engine is the same instance. Any ideas why the retranslate function is not working?

Thanks for the help!

**main.cpp :**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include "translationhandler.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    TranslationHandler transHndl(&engine);

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("translateHandler", &transHndl);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}
```

---

**TranslationHandler.h :**

```
#ifndef TRANSLATIONHANDLER_H
#define TRANSLATIONHANDLER_H
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QString>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QQmlEngine>

class TranslationHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString emptyString READ getEmptyString NOTIFY languageChanged)

public:
    explicit TranslationHandler(QQmlEngine *engine)
    {
        m_translator1 = new QTranslator(this);
        m_currentLanguage = "en";
        m_engine = engine;
    }

    QString getEmptyString()
    {
        return "";
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE QString getCurrentLanguage()
    {
        return m_currentLanguage;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void selectLanguage(QString language)
    {
        if(language == QString("jp"))
        {
            m_currentLanguage = language;
            m_translator1->load(":/translation/qml_jp.qm");
            qGuiApp->installTranslator(m_translator1);
            m_engine->retranslate();
        }
        if(language == QString("en"))
        {
            m_currentLanguage = language;
            qGuiApp->removeTranslator(m_translator1);
            m_engine->retranslate();
        }
        emit languageChanged();
    }

signals:
    void languageChanged();

private:
    QTranslator *m_translator1;
    QString m_currentLanguage;
    QQmlEngine *m_engine;

public slots:
};

#endif // TRANSLATIONHANDLER_H
```

Comment: You know the purpose of the emptyString?

Comment: it is no longer necessary to use that empty String if you use a version of Qt >= 5.10

Comment: The empty string is the only thing that is working with this example. I've added the empty string to one Text and that is the only Text that is changed when a new language is set

Comment: Note that there is a bug with strings contained in PropertyChanges elements (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66541), fixed in Qt 5.11 Beta

Comment: Maybe it might be a problem with qsTr within a `ListElement` aswell, since that is where most of my strings are.

Comment: anyone found a solution that doesn't involve updating it to 5.12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was confirmed as a bug and will be fixed in version 5.12. If you want to compile it yourself please check the bug report

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68350

Comment: was a solution found to have it work on a version prior to 5.12? thanks

Comment: @Nmaster88 I didn't find a way before bug fix, sorry.